# click button from parent page to cause usercontrol's gridview change to different pageindex

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls

I have a button, a usercontrol which contains a gridview in a page.

How do I click the button in the page and cause its usercontrol's gridview to change to a certain pageindex?

Comment: Provide a public method in your UserControl (f.e. `GotoPage(int index)`). Then you can change it from your page by `MyControl.GotoPage(111);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a public method in your UserControl (f.e. `GotoPage(int index)`). Then you can change it from your page by `MyControl.GotoPage(111);`.

`GotoPage` could be implemented as:

```
public void GotoPage(int index)
{
    //side-note: you can call BindGrid(e.NewPageIndex) also from GridView's PageIndexChanging
    BindGrid(index);
}
```

and `BindGrid` could be implemented as:

```
private void BindGrid(int newPageIndex)
{
    // set it's DataSource
    var pageIndex = newPageIndex < 0 || newPageIndex >= GridView1.PageCount ? 0 : newPageIndex;
    GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    // DataBind it
}
```

Comment: I combined these 2 method: in the gotopage, first set gridview's pageindex to the index in the parameter and bind the gridview again that's it.

Comment: @Meidi: Of course that works also. I'm always trying to encapsulate and provide public  methods  as less as possible. Otherwise theres a great danger of hard-linking pages with usercontrols.